# What to do with transactionReceipt deprecation for IAP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, receipt-validation

I am currently validating `transaction.transactionReceipt` base64encoded as a string server side. The problem is that `transaction.transactionReceipt` is deprecated now and I don't know what to replace this with for in app purchases.

The new documentation suggests using `NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];`
, but the docs say that it is only for app purchase validation and not for in app purchases.

What do I do in this case?

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) states that the in app purchases will all be listed in that receipt.

Comment: Right, but if the user purchases unique in app purchases every day, does this call change? Right now it's all at the transaction level so every purchase can be validated.

Comment: I believe that the app receipt will change with every transaction, but I have not confirmed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deprecated TransactionReceipt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682663/deprecated-transactionreceipt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be read in other parts of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW3) the receipt does contain the data for IAP as well. I've also verified this from my own experience, as this is the way we did it where I worked. Basically the only change is that instead of having a receipt for each IAP there is a single one for both the app and all IAPs.

My guess however is that the URL remains the same, although I haven't verified it, but the data contained at the URL changes.

Comment: So does this mean the receipt updates after every in app purchase and contains all previous in app purchases?