# iOS app to MacOS error: 'transactionReceipt' is unavailable: not available on macCatalyst

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, porting, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS/iPadOS app already published and selling in the App Store. Now with the "automatic" port of Xcode 11.1 to MacOS 10.15 Catalina or higher, I just marked the "Mac" checkbox and tried to run the app on my Mac, but I got this compile error:

'transactionReceipt' is unavailable: not available on macCatalyst

How to solve? I'm using StoreKit framework, have to use another one? Is there a way to adapt StoreKit to make it work with macCatalyst?

Comment: What does "solve" mean? The meaning of the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: I'm using StoreKit framework, have to use another one? Is there a way to adapt StoreKit to make it work with macCatalyst?

Comment: What `transactionReceipt` property are you referring to? The one on `SKPaymentTransaction` which was deprecated back in iOS 7?

Comment: Well, in this Apple page it looks like it's not deprecated, it says Class
SKPaymentTransaction is for iOS 3.0+ macOS 10.7+ Mac Catalyst 13.0+ and tvOS 9.0+:

[link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction)

Comment: @Heitor The class, yes. But that's not what you said. You said `transactionReceipt`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1617722-transactionreceipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s all about replacing:

```
transaction.transactionReceipt
```

with:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
```

Found it on [this SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683358/3063226). In my case there was no need to convert NSData to NSString.